# How can i parse simple json response in fetch call

Tags: json, reactjs, fetch

I am getting simple json object in fetch response.when I am trying to access that,it is getting caught in catch.

```
this my reposnse
{
    "islogin": true
}



 fetch(url, data)
      .then(res => {console.log(res);return res.json()})
      .then(
        (result) => {
          console.log("rsult",JSON.stringify(result));
          console.log(result.islogin);
          console.log("1");
          console.log("authentication success");
        })
      .catch((error) => { window.alert("error", error);
        console.log("authentication failed");
      });
```

i am expecting result.islogin to be true/false.But it is not going into then(result) call back.

Comment: So, what do you get in your `alert` (and why not log it use it console.error instead)? Cause if it's not going in your then result, then it should go into your catch instead.

Comment: The way you're doing it (returning `res.json()` from the first `then` handler and then using the parsed data in the second) is correct. You have [an unrelated error](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2018/06/common-fetch-errors.html) [edit: actually, it may not be unrelated], but you should be seeing the correct result from your second `then` handler **if** the JSON being returned is really as shown in the question. The unrelated(?) error is that you're not checking whether the HTTP operation succeeded. The `fetch` API is (in my view) poorly-designed, HTTP errors are fulfillments, not rejections.

Comment: **Always** quote error messages when you're asking about something that results in an error.

Comment: I could succesfully hit the url with status code 200 in chrome but in  fetch response it is showing status code as '0'.How can i solve this.

Answer (score 5):

```
fetch(URL, {
    method: "POST", // "GET/POST"
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(data)
})
.then(r => r.json())
.then(r => {
   console.log('Response', r) // You will get JSON response here.
}).catch(error => console.error('Error', error))
```

I have ran into similiar issue because of the missing Content-Type Header and sometimes because of not stringifying the request payload. Try this code and see whether it's working. Above is the working snippet which I'm using for my project.